# Как покрасить яндекс карту?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как покрасить яндекс карту, чтобы было примерно так [image: карта]

Answer (score 1):

Все есть в документации к yandex maps api
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/dg/concepts/style.html